# How can I create a hierarchal book view page?

Tags: 8, views

I created a node book with the following structure:

- Introduction
- Volume 1

  - Chapter 1
  - Chapter 2
  - Chapter 3
- Volume 2

  - Chapter 1
  - Chapter 2
  - Chapter 3
- Volume 3

  - Chapter 1

I'm trying to create a view that shows them all in a single page but i cant get them to be sorted in the correct way and it's causing the view to load pages in the wrong order. The expected order should be
Intro, volume 1, chapter 1, chapter 2, chapter 3, volume 2, ...etc

I currently have the view relationship set to the top level book and a contextual filter for the node id with a relationship to the top level book id. they are sorted by book depth in descending order but it doesn't match the book hierarchy. Any help with creating this view would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your view showing, the book navigation?  If the goal is to get the list of book navigation links, you can do this with a block easily: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/skilling/administration/set-up-book-navigation-blocks

Comment: By concept Views can not make hierarchical lists, only flat list like in a SQL query. You can "emulate" one level of hierarchry with grouping, but as a rule of thumb: do not use Views when you want hierarchy. Maybe take a look at the book module or the taxonomy module, they have better options when it comes to hierarchy.

Comment: I was trying to get the view to display a flat version of the hierarchy but right now it just shows the chapters first. The view is meant to display full pages and not the book navigation as the book module already has a block for that.